# Outlet side of my cast iron radiator is cold. What's wrong?

Tags: repair

Im in need of some immediate insight!!!! I have a 3 unit building with the old cast iron radiators which are fed by a circulatory pump which was just changed 2 weeks ago i drained the whole system replaced new bearings in the pump works fine, all radiators are working fine but one in the basement front room the inlet is hot to the touch but the radiator itself is cold as well as the outlet , what can be the problem? oh i did bleed the valves on these radiators.

Comment: is the outlet connected? otherwise it may be a water lock or general clog

Comment: Yes its connected and in use but outlet side is cold.

Answer (score 2):

Given "I drained the whole system" I'd suspect a trapped air bubble first and foremost. Try bleeding again. The bubble may be trapped in the pipe rather than the radiator itself - look for bleeders along the pipes. Alternatively there may be a valve you've missed, or an actual bit of debris plugging the radiator (a pretty distant third place, in my experience.)